# Python namespace packaging (symlinks)

Tags: python, packaging, python-packaging

Hi I would like to create a package, which is just a shell around other repos (that maybe used independently of it). Is there a way to do this with namespace packaging, maybe to create a single wheel file for the entire library and potentially without having to have terrible import names for all the sub-repos that are being stitched together.

For example, if `foo` is the parent repo, I'd like to be able to do:

`from foo import bar`

And if someone would like to install just `bar`:

`import bar`